# How to overcome tessnet memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

I tried tessnet library which is a wrapper of Tessract OCR engine in my personal project. But I found that Tessnet current version has many memory leaks. After 30 OCR times, the memory allocated for my app increase upto 500MB. Could you please tell me how to get over this memory leak problem? Is there any better solution? I only know C# and can use only .NET library in app.
Hope to hear from you expert guys soon.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show relevant code. Do you dispose properly, and especially the bitmaps it reads?

Comment: I'm sure that I do dispose the bitmap correctly. I checked several tessnet example projects downloaded from the internet. They have the same problem with my app.

Comment: Tessnet is a wrapper for Tesseract, which is old and full of memory leaks! The solution below to dispose often is probably the best one.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by calling .Dispose() on all of the bitmaps I created, after I did what I needed with them. I also did the same thing for the bitmap included in the TessNetOCR object.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(...);

TessNetOCR ocr = new TessNetOCR(tessnetlocation, lang, bmp, false, false);

(code using ocr and bmp)

ocr.Image.Dispose();

bmp.Dispose();
```

edit: I should note that the program was using a ton of memory, and calling dispose on my image objects freed this memory, and resolved the memory leak issue.